# Why should I use NSFetchedResultsController in a hierarchical ViewController structure?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I searched a bit but couldn't find the answer I was actually looking for. Simple scenario:

`TableViewController` with an `NSArray` of `beers`. If I select the cell, a detail-view with `beer details` should be displayed. Now the beers are stored using `CoreData`.

In the `RootViewController` I use `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch all the beers.

Now my question is: Should I just set the **beer** property of the destination to the selected beer, or should I create a new `NSFetchedResultsController` and perform a whole new fetch with a set up `NSPredicate`?

Where is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm...

For me I think the biggest factor would be whether the data changes or not.

`NSFetchedResultsController` is good for performing fetches etc... but it comes into its own when dealing with CoreData entities that change.

The `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods are there to update the table/collection view when the CoreData model is updated on a background thread (i.e. from a network request etc...).

If your model doesn't change at all then I'd go with just passing the `beer` object in and using the properties of that object.

If the model does change then use the `NSFRC` and its delegate methods to perform a new fetch.

Answer (score 2):

If you already hold the selected object in your `RootViewController` and it has all attributes that you will present in the detailViewController, then I see no point setting up the `NSFetchedResultController` for the detailVC. You can just pass the object to detail in prepareForSegue or so.

The point of using `NSFetchedController` is that you don't have to update your tableview datasource array and reload rows/table with each change in your list provided you use Apple's `CoreDataTableViewController` template.